# "Installation Failed" error trying to install Red Giant Plugin in OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, osx-lion, after-effects

I recently migrated from PC to Mac and I am trying to install the Red Giant Trapcode Plugin trial for After Effects, but I keep getting an "installation failed" error. I downloaded the installer directly from the plugin source and I checked compatibility issues --it is compatible with OS X EL Capitan 10.11.6, my OS. Other people have installed it without any issues. I checked firewall and Filevault and they are off. I have read that when people get this kind of error in Mac  it has to do with permission rights or something active in their OS but I don't know what to check to fix it.  [This is the error I get](http://i67.tinypic.com/2wrgt9y.jpg). Any insight to point me in the right direction will be very greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

ADDITIONAL INFO: I tried looking into the install logs and I see that I get this on trying to install:

(trust evaluation failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=106 "The package “%@” is missing or invalid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The package “%@” is missing or invalid., identifier=com.redgiant.postflight})

Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “GrowBoundsforParticularAECC15.3.pkg”."

Sep 23 16:17:17 Saras-iMac Installer[918]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue installing Red Giant Products on my iMac running macOS Sierra v 10.12.1. After pulling my hair out for a while, I realized that another user account was running in the background. When I switched to that user, logged her out, and returned to my own user account, I was able to install the Red Giant products without any issues.  Hope this helps!